How to disable Jupyter Notebook in VSCode
When I click on "New file" in VS Code, it asks me whether I want to open a new file or a new Jupyter notebook. At the moment, I can safely say I never want a Jupyter notebook as I don't use Python at all. Hence I'd rather have it simply open a new text file immediately, instead of asking to chose.
I am asking exactly the same as this question, but none of the answers there seem to reply to the actual question. They focus on how to open Jupyter Notebooks in the text editor by default, which is not what was asked. Furthermore, the settings mentioned in the accepted answer do not exist anymore, or only work when you have the Python extension. But I'd rather not have to install Python or Jupyter extensions just to tell VS Code that I never use Python and Jupyter.

As explained, the situation is not the same. They were using Python and had a reason to install Python and Jupyter extensions. I don't write any Python code, so I wouldn't want to clutter my setup with extensions for languages and features I'll never use. That would be like having to register an Apple account and install iTunes on my Windows just to be able to get rid of an mp3 context menu item "Buy on iTunes".

well, you're going to be disappointed to find out that VS Code includes basic support for many languages out of the box: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions (which you can disable). It also include basic support for notebook editors out of the box, in a way that is supposed to be abstracted away from Jupyter notebooks.

@user "which you can disable" So can I disable support for notebooks? I obviously don't object there being native features that I don't use, and I don't mind them as long as they don't clutter the experience of the feature I do use. But if they do, I appreciate options to turn them off without necessity of adding clutter elsewhere as trade-off.
